# Firefox automatically choose certificate, without ui dialog

Tags: firefox, ssl, automation, certificate, ui-automation

Is there a way to choose the specific default client certificate for authentication on web-resources? In the prefs.js in firefox app data folder, there is a line:

`security.default_personal_cert`

I changed its value to:

`Select Automatically`

And now it is selecting the first certificate for site avaliable. I want basically to automatate this process (with imacros and few other tools). Is there a way i can set a **SPECIFIC certificate as default client certificate?** Maybe i have missed somethign else?

Comment: Have the same issue. Haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement this, but probably not very useful, and I do not believe it is implemented in Firefox.

Servers are usually configured with a specific CA certificate (or set thereof) to use for validating client certificates.  The TLS [Certificate Request message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.4) will usually advertise the *Issuer Distinguished Name*s of these CA certificates in the `certificate_authorities` field, which the client will then use to select an appropriate certificate to supply in the [Client Certificate message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.6).  In particular:

> If the `certificate_authorities` list in the certificate request
> message was non-empty, one of the certificates in the certificate
> chain SHOULD be issued by one of the listed CAs.

An "always use this certificate" option would be useful only in the case where the server does not advertise which CA(s) it intends to use to validate client certificates (I have never seen this situation before).  Normally, the *Select Automatically* heuristic will Do The Right Thing.

If you need an *automated* way to choose a particular certificate where you have multiple certificates for the same site, Firefox provides the option of multiple profiles.  You can have a single certificate in each profile, which will be automatically chosen.  It is inconvenient but I do not know of another way.

Comment: but the problem is, i have a lot of client certificates for one site, `Select Automatically` will do the right thing, but it will always select one same certificate (latest issued for this site). I just wanted to move across them somehow, without selecting the certificate from ui control. Is it possible with certutil maybe?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to configure this in Firefox.  `certutil` definitely doesn't help here.  If you need an automated way without UI prompt, separate profiles are an option (I will add to my answer).

Comment: is it not possible to maybe re-order the certificates using like certutil?

Comment: Even if you could my hunch is that the selection heuristic will choose the certificate based on validity period.

Comment: So there is no easy way.. By any chance is there anything you know about the engine? I guess i could possibly, try and hook the function which is doing the selection, i mean when you select it manually it must call some sort of api, passing there either certificate, or global index. If could inject library and hook it, i might then change the index. If the certs getting from cert.db i could try and hook `ReadFile` to see where it goes after that..

Comment: in the certutil.c i found a call to `SECU_FindCertByNicknameOrFilename` and `CERT_FindCertByDERCert`, guees i can try to hook both of those and see what can i obtain from them.